# Linux/Postfix with relay: I can openssl to relay host on port 465, but postfix does not seem to connect

Tags: linux, ssl, smtp, postfix

This looks like a tough one to me: I'm configuring postfix on my local home server running ubuntu server 14.04 LTS I was able to send outgoing mail through my relayhost on port 26, everything worked I'm now trying to send outgoing mail through my relayhost on port 465, and I get postfix error "lost connection with [relayhost] while receiving the initial server greeting" I can openssl and EHLO fine from the command line though, so it must be a postfix configuration issue

my master.cf has

```
smtps inet n - - - - smtpd
```

uncommented as required

my main.cf has

```
...
relayhost = relayhostname.tld:465

smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_type = cyrus
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
...
```

and obviously I configured sasl_passwd etc.

Any ideas?

Thank you p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postfix `relayhost` option doesn't support SMTPS connection.

If you want to enforce the `relayhost` disabling MX lookup, you should use the hostname between "[" and "]".

If you want to enforce SMTPS connection, you can create a local tunnel with `stunnel`:

```
[smtp-tls-wrapper]
accept = 11125
client = yes
connect = mail.example.com:smtps
```

You can get more info on http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html

Comment: Thanks I just figured that out

But now I am getting my outbound messages returned with a
"host 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] said: 554 5.4.0 Error: too
    many hops (in reply to end of DATA command)"

email message...!!

Comment: Looks like you've got a loop. Change the `relayhost` to use the accept port defined in stunnel: `relayhost = [127.0.0.1]:11125`.

Comment: I have that already so the loop must be elsewhere...  given how quickly I'm getting the 554 error I'm guessing the loop is local, is there any way I can track all the connections made?

Comment: @phaedo You can check in your maillog, probably in `/var/log/maillog` or `/var/log/mail.log`.

Comment: #tail /var/log/mail.log
postfix/smtpd[23427]: Anonymous TLS connection established from localhost[127.0.0.1]: TLSv1.2 with cipher AECDH-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits)
postfix/smtpd[23427]: A001D84215B: client=localhost[127.0.0.1], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=[user name]@[local host name.tld]
postfix/smtp[23420]: 8792D842160: to=<test@example.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:12345, delay=0.1, delays=0.06/0/0.04/0, dsn=5.4.0, status=bounced (host 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] said: 5545.4.0 Error: too many hops (in reply to end of DATA command))
 postfix/smtpd[23427]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]

Comment: Looks like you've doing a TLS connection to your own server. Check `connect` line in stunnel if it is set to your outside `relayhost`. Your postfix should point to stunnel which is pointed to your real relayhost.

Comment: `stunnel.conf` says `connect = [relay host.tld]:smtps` as required...!

Comment: @phaedo manual says `connect = [host:]port` meaning that host is optional.

Comment: did I misunderstand stunnel.conf? I have `accept = 127.0.0.1:12345`, `client = yes`, `connect = [relayhost.tld:]smtps`, `delay = yes`

Comment: just change `connect = relayhost.tld:smtps`, no `[]`

Comment: I tried that already :) no luck.  I have a feeling my stunnel connection isn't working properly, because if I `telnet 127.0.0.1 12345` I get greeted by my local machine ESMTP rather than the relay host's ESMTP...!!

Comment: If you stop stunnel and still get local machine ESMTP that means that postfix is binding on port 12345.

Comment: Yes I stopped stunnel and I still get local machine ESMTP on port 12345...  But isn't Postfix supposed to listen to 12345?

Comment: @phaedo To solve your problem, change the stunnel port to something else, like that I've written in example. The `relayhost` configuration on postfix makes it connect to that address when it try to send an e-mail, it is not supposed to listen in this port. If you want to know what is running there: `netstat -tapn | grep 12345`

Comment: ok step by step: I changed the port to 10465 in stunnel.conf, I restarted stunnel, I did `netstat -tapn |grep 10465` and it shows nothing!

Comment: OK I fixed stunnel.  The loop was created by a line in postfix's `master.cf` file whereby postfix listened to port 12345.  Removing that line stopped the loop.  But now my outgoing messages through the relay host bounce back with error 550.  Will investigate this new issue...!  Thanks for your patience and help.